# How to filter HTML's content of a web site to a WinRT c# App?

Tags: c#, html, windows-8

I'm developing a Windows Store Application that filter [the GsmArena site](http://www.gsmarena.com/) and show informations of all smartphones to the user.
But, I have no ideia how to get this informations. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extract such info with [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Using Firefox, view page source, you can find the correspondence of the visual rendering with the html: 
[image]

and then you will find that each phone's info is wrapped inside a div class "news-item", then try below snippet to exact all new items:

```
private const string RemoteRoot = @"http://www.gsmarena.com/";
private WebClient _client = new WebClient();
_client.DownloadFile(remoteLink, localPath);  //Save it to a local file
```

or you can use Html Agility Pack to download a file from web:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(remoteLink);
doc.Save(localPath);
```

Then you can retrieve the info you need:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(localPath);
var filter = string.Format(@"//*[@class='{0}']", "news-item");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(filter); // here you have all new items
//you can then retrive h3 texts etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, the tag is relevant 'cause some classes doesn't exists for WinRT, WebClient for example, it's just a way to call attention. :)

Comment: OK, got it. BTW: WebClient is just one approach to download the file from web, you can use Html Agility Pack to download a file as well.

Comment: 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/359358
This answer of a  forum suggest Descendants() functions and LINQ to get Nodes. Do you know something about it?
Using Html Agility Pack is possible get media elements too?

Comment: actually it is the case for WinRT, which has no support for XPath so far. You are right in that, the windows-8 tag might be important, but I might agree more if windows-8 is replaced with "windows store app" or "winrt", since we can run .net application on windows 7? :)